# API request in Node returning error

Tags: node.js, rest, http

I am making a simple http request to the Sphere Engine API with some request parameters . However, I cannot interpret the error .
API specification : http://sphere-engine.com/services/docs/compilers#status

Code:

```
http = require('http') ;

var info = {
    sourceCode: 'print 3+4',
    language: 4,
    input: ''
} ;

var infoString = JSON.stringify(info);

var options = {
    host: 'api.compilers.sphere-engine.com',
    port: 80,
    path: '/api/v3/submissions?access_token=b11bf50b8a391d4e8560e97fd9d63460',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': infoString.length
    }
} ;

var req = http.request(options,function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf-8');
    var responseString = '' ;
    res.on('data', function(data) {
        responseString += data ;
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
        var resultObject = JSON.parse(responseString);
    });
} );

req.write(infoString);
req.end();
```

Error:

```
undefined:0

^
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/sarthakmunshi/nodetry.js:29:27)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:943:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

Comment: The error simply says that the responseString is HTML instead of JSON. I have a strong suspicion that it's the login page. You can get a better clue by printing out the responseString before you try to `JSON.parse()` it.

Comment: I had a doubt. Is the method mentioned above similar to making a curl request with some parameters. if not, how can i make it that way ?

Comment: Inside the `res.on('end'..)` simply print out (console.log) the `responseString` and comment out `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: i get a json object `{"error":"WRONG_LANG_ID"}` . n0ow is this an api error i guess !?

Answer (score 2):

This error caused by `JSON.parse(responseString);`. You get response as not-json string (XML, HTML?), but try to parse it as a json.

You can use [xml-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-stream) library to parse XML.

Comment: how do i use it for converting xml to json . documentation is a bit confusing .

Comment: The response is not XML. It's HTML. Specifically HTML 2.0, not even XHTML. Parsing HTML as XML will result in errors because HTML have tags that breaks XML rules

Comment: @slebetman probably you right, I can't see the API specification because it's behind the login page. Obviously it's not a JSON.

Comment: @saru95 it's really easy. Just create xmlStream object, define callbacks for nodes/attributes you're interested in and pipe http response stream into it.